# Excel duplicating any word text in different cells

Tags: excel

I have "**India is my country**" in cell A1, and "**my dream to visit india**" in cell B1.

I want to highlight the word *india* and *my* as it there in both cells without typing the word *india* or *my* anywhere in the formula, because I have 1000 of rows to find out different matching word.

Comment: 'Highlight' them how? And how are the different matching words going to be passed to the formula?

Comment: Do you want the words in **A1** hi-lighted  or the words in **B1** hi-lighted ??

Comment: " i want to highlight the word 'india' and 'my' as it there in both cells without typing the word 'india' or 'my' anywhere in the formula. " - How do you expect Excel to know to extract these words, if you don't put them in the formula? Or are you saying you have a list of such words to extract, and we can use that, instead of manually adding in "india" and "my".

Comment: @Werrf:  actually i have my customer name in a excel sheet. Now i have done survey for customer details. Some names are not typed exactly same in the excel sheet which i have already. but some part of the customer name is same. for eg: company name in my old list is 'Marfa limited', newly typed in the survey excel sheet is ' The Marfa Private limited'

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: in Both

Comment: @BruceWayne Why cant highlight same word in the both cell. i need formula in this way?

Comment: A formula will not highlight a word in another cell.  You will need vba to highlight the words.

Comment: As @ScottCraner said, a formula can't highlight text within a cell. As a rule, a formula can only change the contents of the cell in which it is entered, it can't make changes to another cell, and it can't make formatting changes.

We could use Conditional Formatting to highlight cells that contain "India" and "My", or we could use VBA to highlight the text.

Comment: I think we may be working on an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What do you want to do in the end here?  A quick option, for each row, would be send the cell info to "Text to Columns" (in the Data tab), using a space as a delimiter.  That will put each word in its own cell. Then, you can use conditional formatting (no VBA needed) to highlight whatever words.  Although again, you'll need a list of such duplicate words somewhere to use as your rule. If you just need to know if such words are duplicates, then you can use perhaps `countif`

Comment: some characters do have   unicode versions, but still not possible with only formulas http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=Negative+squared